# Failed review audit - was I correct or not?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed an audit on the <kbd>Close votes</kbd> queue due to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8087322). IMO the question is not a good one as clearly you can find out if a string is an array if you try to write some VBA code. Also the OP says that `It is not behaving as I would expect`, without giving any extra details.

I'm assuming that the question was catalogued as good due to the 12 votes, however I find it at least incomplete.

Am I incorrectly evaluating this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a high-quality question?
It's coherent and clear, though it's quite basic.
Being basic does not in itself make it bad, only a probable duplicate.
The C++/C example (which can be seen as a more formal pseudocode) might lead to questions how exactly the semantics relate (which would be good to answer), but it can just be ignored.

Does it deserve closing?
Unless you find a duplicate (I didn't try), for what reason?
It is answerable like that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was distracted by the `It is not behaving as I would expect` part of the question, which made me incorrectly evaluate the question.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, look at the question at *face value*.  Strings being represented as null-terminated arrays has gone on for a long time, but perhaps we didn't know if that applied to VB as well.

Is the question coherent?  That is, is the question written clearly enough, or written enough that it doesn't need more edits/clarification from the OP?

In my opinion this question is fine.  Even if it were a duplicate, the question itself is *fine*.  There's nothing wrong with it here and I'm having a tough time finding faults with it.